# Brace usage error while using curl with in bash

Tags: bash, curl, jq, quoting

Following curl usage is not liking braces inside braces. I tried escaping but it didnt help ... any ideas?

```
echo "$(curl -s -u ${USERNAME}:${PASSWORD} GET ${hostName}/${path}.json| jq -r -c '[.field1,.field2] | \"(.[0]) ,(.[1])"')"
```

Result:

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER (Unix shell
quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:

error near (.[0]`)`
```

Comment: `echo "$(some commands)"` is almost always a mistake, and is complicating the quoting here. Why not run the commands directly, and skip capturing and echoing the output?

Comment: What are you hoping `\"(.[0]) ,(.[1])"` would do?

Comment: You do know none of the curly braces are required? You only need them if the next character is part of a valid variable name.  As above, not sure why you have only one double quote escaped?

Comment: This is a `jq` error, not a `curl` error: you forgot to escape the closing `"` in the `jq` command. You are, however, missing the `-X` argument before `GET`. (Either `-X GET` or omit `GET`, as that is the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug cases like this, it's best to break things down into the basic components first.  In your case, I'd guess you intended the jq filter to be:

```
[.field1,.field2] | "\(.[0]), \(.[1])"
```

To test:

```
 jq -r -c '[.field1,.field2] | "\(.[0]), \(.[1])"'
 {"field1": 1, "field2": 2}
 1, 2
```

Once you have that part right, the rest is easy.  Assuming you are using a decent shell, you could probably make life simple for yourself by using `$()` rather than `"$()"`, or avoiding command substitution altogether.

From the development and testing point of view, it might make sense to put the jq program that you know to be correct into a file, say program.jq, and then you can in sequence:

(a) verify it in stand-alone mode, using `jq -r -c -f program.jq`

(b) plug the jq invocation into your pipeline to verify that there isn't another problem elsewhere.

If using program.jq isn't ultimately satisfactory, you might want to consider setting a shell variable to the jq program, e.g.

```
JQ='[.field1,.field2] | "\(.[0]), \(.[1])"'

echo $(jq -r -c "$JQ")
```

Of course the last line above is just there for testing.  Maybe you don't even need `$()` at all?

Comment: thanks it worked... i was using this inside jenkins shell ... i mistook it when it highlighted font in red..but it worked